# What is it called when two images from different locations are blended seamlessly into one?

Tags: terminology, compositing

I have compiled two images to become one.  The one image is from Nova Scotia and the other in Utah.  I placed the Utah image on top of the top half of the image from Nova Scotia and it looks like it's all one image.

Is there a technical name for this type of compilation?  Many people would not recognize that these are two different images.

Answer (score 2):

A "composite picture" is probably what you are looking for.

Answer (score 1):

It is called compositing, and the seamless blending is sometimes called stitching.

Answer (score 0):

I have also come across the word "Image Merging"